# Can't establish the connection with bootnode and two nodes

Tags: private-blockchain

I have problem with starting my private network.

Two nodes on different PC and with external IP addresses, starts with next parameters:

```
--verbosity 3 --identity "TestNet" --rpc --rpcport "8081" --rpccorsdomain "*" 
--datadir "%datadir%" --port 25565 
--rpcapi "admin,debug,miner,shh,txpool,personal,eth,net,web3" 
--bootnodes "enode//:ID@IP:port" 
--networkid 255655 console
```

Bootnode starts on third PC with own external IP address too::

```
 --nodekey geth/bootnode.key --verbosity 9 --addr "ip:port"
```

Bootnode reports PING\PONGS with both nodes. But they still have 0 peers.

I dont know what to do.
I try to change parameters to discovery5 protocol
     --v5disc --bootnodesv5 (for nodes)
     --v5 (for bootnode)
Bootnode still have strong connection with nodes, but they still have no peers.
And bootnode report error: invalid neighbor : is self

I try to reinitialize nodes, start to mine on one or both. But nothing helps.

What im doing wrong?

Comment: I was just wondering if you ever figured it out, im in the same boat